# How can i write update query with condition in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
public String passlink(String companyName, String mailName) {

    Session session = Hibernateutil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String queryString="UPDATE account SET companyname = :companyName WHERE companyname like 'm' AND Email LIKE :mailName";
        Query query=session.createQuery(queryString);

        query.setParameter("companyName", companyName);
        query.setParameter("mailName", mailName);
        int result = query.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result);

            System.out.println("Successfully updated");
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        value = "FAIL";
                   e.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println("Error--> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return value;

}
```

I write update query

String queryString="UPDATE account SET companyname = :companyName WHERE companyname like 'm' AND Email LIKE :mailName";

like this but it gives following error.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>       at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.postProcessUpdate(HqlSqlWalker.java:390)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:164)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:130)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:83)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getQuery(SessionFactoryImpl.java:425)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getQueries(SessionImpl.java:880)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:861)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:89)
>       at com.njob.dao.AccountDao.passlink(AccountDao.java:213)
>       at com.njob.action.companylink.doPost(companylink.java:34)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:825)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:731)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:526)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the query to

```
String queryString="UPDATE account SET companyname = :companyName WHERE companyname like 'm' AND email LIKE :mailName";
```

and use

```
query.setParameter("companyName", companyName);
query.setParameter("mailName", mailName);
```

---

**See**

- [Native SQL query with hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Comment: It gives the same error Parameter companyname does not exist as a named parameter

Comment: There was a typo if you see `companyName` in query

Comment: well its `companyName` not the `companyname`, try copy and paste from my answer

Comment: That's an IndexOutOfBounds exception, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019281/hibernate-executeupdate-indexoutofbounds

Comment: add `e.printStacktrace()` in catch block and post its output

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 query.setParameter("companyName", companyName);
```

The parameter you use is companyName